# Intuition for the Poisson kernel

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The derivation of the Poisson kernel for a disc seems to involve a trick, and I don't really understand how one would come up with it.

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a disc $D_{R_0}$ centered at the origin and of radius $R_0$.

We are aiming for some sort of integral representation of $f$ with a real-valued kernel, which ends up to be

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(Re^{i\varphi}) \text{Re}\left(\frac{Re^{\varphi} + z}{Re^{i\varphi} - z}\right) \; d\varphi$$

So the trick used is to write

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{D_{R_0}} f(\zeta)/(\zeta-z) - f(\zeta)/(\zeta-R^2/\bar{z}) \; d\zeta$$

I'm not sure how one would come up with adding $f(\zeta)/(\zeta-R^2/\bar{z})$, except for the fact that it magically seems to work. I've tried working backwards, but it really hasn't given me any new insight into the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f$ be holomorphic on the closed disc $\bar{D}_R$. Let $z\in D_R$. Then
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\text{Re}\Bigl(\frac{Re^{i\theta} + z}{Re^{i\theta} - z}\Bigr)d\theta
$$

---

Consider for simplicity where $z = re^{i\theta}$
$$
\frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} = \frac{1 - \lvert z\rvert^2}{|z - e^{i\phi}\rvert^2} = \frac{e^{i\phi}}{e^{i\phi} - z}+ \frac{e^{-i\phi}}{e^{-i\phi} - \bar{z}} - 1
$$
Also, note that the space of Harmonic functions is generated by the identity $z\mapsto z$ and $z\mapsto\bar{z}$.

---

**Proof**

Let $z = re^{i\phi}$, and let $C_R$ be the circle of radius $R$, parametrized by $\zeta = Re^{i\theta}$ so $d\zeta = iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$. By Cauchy's Theorem,
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}d\zeta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\frac{Re^{i\theta}}{Re^{i\theta} - re^{i\phi}}d\theta\tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, let $z' = R^2/\bar{z} = e^{i\phi}R^2/r$. Therefore, $\zeta\mapsto\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z'}$ is holomorphic on $\bar{D}_R$.
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z'}d\zeta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta} - Re^{i\phi}}d\theta\tag{2}
\end{align}
Now subtract (1) and (2) to get
$$
\frac{R^2 - r^2}{R^2 - 2rR\cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} = \text{Re}\Bigl(\frac{Re^{i\theta} + re^{i\phi}}{Re^{i\theta} - re^{i\phi}}\Bigr)
$$

Comment: A stupid question, but how did you get the following result in $(3)$ ? $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\frac{Re^{i\theta}}{Re^{i\theta} - re^{i\phi}}d\theta \, \, - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta} - Re^{i\phi}}d\theta =  \text{Re}\Bigl(\frac{Re^{i\theta} + re^{i\phi}}{Re^{i\theta} - re^{i\phi}}\Bigr) \tag{3}$$

Comment: @Zophikel You subtract equation (1) and (2) which yields what you call (3)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, we have a power series representation

$$
f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\dots
$$

that converges in $|z|\le R$. Let $G(r,\theta)=\Re[f(re^{i\theta})]$. Write $a_n=\alpha_n+i\beta_n$, so we have

$$
G(r,\theta)=\alpha_0+\sum_{n\ge1}[\alpha_n\cos(n\theta)-\beta_n\sin(n\theta)]r^n.\tag1
$$

Using the properties of Fourier series, if $g(\phi)=G(R,\phi)$, then we have

$$
\alpha_0={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(\phi)\mathrm d\phi
$$

and for $n\ge1$ that

$$
\alpha_nR^n=\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}g(\phi)\cos(n\phi)\mathrm d\phi,
$$

$$
-\beta_nR^n=\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}g(\phi)\sin(n\phi)\mathrm d\phi.
$$

Plugging these into (1), we obtain

$$
G(r,\theta)={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(\phi)P(\phi)\mathrm d\phi,\tag2
$$

in which

\begin{aligned}
P(\phi)
&=1+2\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac rR\right)^n[\cos(n\theta)\cos(n\phi)+\sin(n\theta)\sin(n\phi)] \\
&=1+2\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac rR\right)^n\cos[n(\theta-\phi)]=1+2\Re\left[\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac rR\cdot e^{i(\theta-\phi)}\right)^n\right] \\
&=1+\Re\left(2re^{i\theta}\over Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}\right)=\Re\left(Re^{i\phi}+re^{i\theta}\over Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}\right)
\end{aligned}

Plugging this into (2), we obtain **Poisson integral formula**:

$$
\Re[f(re^{i\theta})]={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\Re[f(Re^{i\phi}]\Re\left(Re^{i\phi}+re^{i\theta}\over Re^{i\phi}-re^{i\theta}\right)\mathrm d\phi.
$$